# Exporting Raster inside a Feature Class

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster, attachments

Using ArcMap 10.0

Trying to export a photo that has been taken with a device which is stored inside of a Feature class table. I have tried to export the data using "Right Click>Data>Export Data" This only exports the other data inside the table, such as the date taken and another attribute.

I am trying to export this layer into QGIS so that the raster layer is still available. So you can see the point, click on it and the photo will show, all in QGIS. Unsure on what needs to be done or if this is even possible.

The raster column is removed when exporting it to .dbf or .shp file extension. Something I am missing here?